# Remove link to source code in doxygen?

Tags: file, doxygen

I want my doxygen output to show only documentation, without showing any raw source code.  I know that it is possible to hide the file browsing tab so that the user can only browse by `namespace`/`class`, and that this effectively hides source.

However, I have lots of functions in a top level namespace that are organized by file only, so I do want to maintain the capability to browse by filename.  I just want to remove the link inside a file doc that says "Go to the source code of this file."  Is there any way to remove this link?

Of course, I could write a script that analyzed all output HTML files and deletes any file ending in `_source.html` and also removes lines of this sort from remaining HTML:

```
<p><a href="FILENAME_8h_source.html">Go to the source code of this file.</a></p>
```

However I was hoping there would be a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 22):

In your configuration file, set the following options:

```
SOURCE_BROWSER = NO
VERBATIM_HEADERS = NO
```

This still lists the namespaces in each file, but does not include the source code.

Comment: This should really be accepted. Also, it helps to use: REFERENCES_LINK_SOURCE = NO